# ESP8266 programming without SDK

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

There are limitations in the ESP SDK libraries (which are not public) like for example the length of the packet recv (112bytes max) when in promisc mode.

I tried reaching them to get some input and directions - but they seem to be replying nonsense.

Is it possible to program the chip without the SDK - thus make my own SDK and forget their limitations?

Comment: the SDK contains a 'softdevice'. it handles the WiFi on analog radio level

Comment: @Juraj - sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: meaning, you cannot speak to the processor like bare metal ?

Comment: to processor maybe you can, but without WiFi capability

Comment: so WiFi isn't a processor you can access ?

Comment: I guess, on esp8266 WiFi is done with software more then on any other device. the point is it can't be replaced without enormous work

Comment: anything you can reffer to - so that i could read? first time hearing 'wifi done with software'. sounds more than interesting

Comment: it is only my impression from experience with the esp8266. see here for alternative to complete Espressif SDK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266#SDKs

Comment: it is funny that all unofficial SDK contain the official SDK. but the part which you want to change is maybe in the open source part

Comment: @Juraj it is unfortunately not in open source. The functionality of the promisc mode is built into a library that has no sources available. See:

wifi_set_promiscuous_rx_cb

I am part of a product development group that plans to build a low-cost wireless intrusion detection system for SOHO. ESP seemed like the choice to go, but with the limitation for 112 bytes per packet in promisc mode, we need to drop this product.

We already delivered a product to a market with 1200 devices based on ESP, but for this new initiative we would have to drop ESP just because of the limits they defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The processor-core on the esp8266 is an 'xtensa'. The processor-core, or let's just call it the processor, is what we program with C or C++ or assembler. The processor's instruction set is made public by the company (which is Tensilica .. or Cadence??) and once you have the instruction set, you can program directly or make a compiler and have complete freedom with the processor.

The processor-core is not the complete product and for us end-consumers, and companies, like Espressif, buy the Intellectual Property rights to a processor-core's design and build an end-product by putting peripherals like SPI, I2C, UART and in the esp8266's case, the wifi-tranceiver, around the processor-core.

These peripherals are controlled digitally, and output to the processor digitally, so the processor can interface with them - but their action can be either digital or analog. For UART, SPI, I2C etc, espressif has provided us with the datasheet that informs of all the registers that can be used to control that peripheral. It's something like write to this X memory address what you want to transfer and then set the bit Y on the Z memory address to begin the transfer. For SPI for example, there are registers to control speed, polarity, phase etc for a transfer. Once you know how to control a peripheral at the lower level, you can write high level drivers, which espressif does provide too, but you can write your own.

For Wifi, espressif hasn't released how the peripheral can be interfaced with, so we have to depend upon the compiled binaries that espressif sends us. You can use 'objdump -t' on the 'lib/lib80211.a' to get atleast the names of the routines that the Wifi driver provides. You can call these routines from C or assembler code and go a little bit lower than espressif intended but to go any lower would require 'Reverse Engineering' by manually understanding the low level code in the compiled Driver and nobody's gonna take that risk and time-drain.

Comment: Thank You, seems like the effort needed is just too much for the results i wanted to achieve.